# Jquery Validate function does not show error placements with Google Invisible Recaptcha?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, recaptcha

My form has only one field, that is "email". I want to verify that if user has not filled "email" field, error should be shown as per following Jquery Validate method using error placement attribute:

```
passwordresetForm.validate({
rules: {
  'email': "required",
},
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  $(error).insertBefore(element);
},
```

});

I am also using following `data-callback` method for google invisible recaptcha on my submit button:

```
 function onSubmit(token) {
    document.getElementById("password-reset-form").submit();
  }
```

However, it seems like this `data-callback` method is taking control once called and not allowing Jquery Validate method to show error even when user is submitting empty "email" field. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you please provide the html code?